# SOAPEngine requestURL -> cannot call value of non-function Type 'NSURL' Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

i download the priore/SOAPEngine from Github. I want to test this framework and want to ask the w3 web service, in the realm from the developer are a test code for these step, but in objective - c. I want that do in swift 2.0 in Xcode 7.1

```
let soap = SOAPEngine()
    soap.actionNamespaceSlash = true

    soap.setValue(txt_cel.text, forKey: "Celsius")

    soap.requestURL("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx",
        soapAction: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit", completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : NSInteger, stringXML : NSString) -> Void in
            lbl_Info.text = "Result :" + soap.floatValue()
        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

            lbl_Info.text = "error"
    }
```

I get a error on soap.reqestURL(...) -> Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSURL'

They have one project in the zip for swift and they do the same:

```
soap.requestURL("http://www.prioregroup.com/services/americanbible.asmx",
        soapAction: "http://www.prioregroup.com/GetVerses",
        completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

            var book:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
            let verses:NSArray = book["BibleBookChapterVerse"] as! NSArray
            self.verses = verses
            self.table.reloadData()

        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

            NSLog("%@", error)
    }
```

can someone help me find the problem in my project?

greetz

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but  http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit doesn't exist, it's a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct declaration is:

```
soap.setValue("30", forKey: "Celsius")
soap.requestURL("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx",
    soapAction: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit",
    completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode: Int, dict : [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Void in

        //let result:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
        NSLog("%f", soap.floatValue());

    }, failWithError: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("%@", error)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay i have the Answer :)
I change this Code:

```
(statusCode : NSInteger, stringXML : NSString)
```

with this

```
(NSInteger statusCode, NSString stringXML )
```

Than i change these Codes:

```
lbl_Info.text = "Result :" + soap.floatValue(); lbl_Info.text = "error"
```

To:

```
self.message = String(soap.floatValue()); self.message = String(error)
```

:) That's It !

Greetz